# Sql Grouping Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering how i can get a query to put these groupings into one line so i can put it into a vb.net datagrid.

For example  Number, Company Name, Current, 31-60, 61-90
Which would be for example company A, but get the grouping to all be on one line.

```
104680777, Company A, 643546.344, 34534534.77, 3454.55
```

To even get this query below. I had to do this.

```
select sum(Amount), DunsNum, CompanyName, Age
from tblARAged
group by DunsNum, Age, CompanyName


Amount      Num        CompanyName             Age  
63546.344   104680777   Company a   1   
34534534.77 104680777   Company a   2   
3454.55 104680777   Company a   3   
3453453.66  186830733   Company b   1   
345342.45   186830733   Company b   2   
4542.55 186830733   Company c   3   
3434.55 26409797    Company c   1   
345345  26409797    Company c   2
```

The 1 correlates to current, 2 correlates to 31-60 and 3 correlates to 61-90 for age

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do what Nimesh stated, though I would make a few tweaks.  You want to do aggregation as late as possible:

`SELECT  DunsNum ,
        CompanyName ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ( Age = 1 ) THEN Amt
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS [Amount_Cur] ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ( Age = 2 ) THEN Amt
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS [Amount_31-60] ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ( Age = 3 ) THEN Amt
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS [Amount_61-90]
FROM    tblARAged
GROUP BY DunsNum ,
        CompanyName;`

I haven't tested this code